# How to Capture/handle Deep links in kotlin android webview app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

I'm trying to handle an external url via my app, this is my xml deeplink code,

```
<activity android:name="com.newdom.hio.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- below line is to set the action to our intent to view -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <!-- on below line we are adding a default category to our intent -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <!-- on below line we are adding a category to make our app browsable -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- on below line we are specifying the host name and
                    the scheme type from which we will be calling our app -->
                <data
                    android:host="www.mynewdom.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- below is the same filter as above just the scheme is changed to http -->
            <!-- so we can open our app with the url starting with https and http as well -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.mynewdom.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- below line is to set the action to our intent to view -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <!-- on below line we are adding a default category to our intent -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <!-- on below line we are adding a category to make our app browsable -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- on below line we are specifying the host name and
                    the scheme type from which we will be calling our app -->
                <data
                    android:host="mynewdom.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- below is the same filter as above just the scheme is changed to http -->
            <!-- so we can open our app with the url starting with https and http as well -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="mynewdom.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It opens my app when the user clicks the link to my domain "www.mynewdom.com" from any other app, But How can i accept/handle the link when it opens my app? I have only MainActivty and so i tred the following code inside `override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` ,

```
private var uri: Uri? = null
 uri = intent.data

                    // checking if the uri is null or not.
                    if (uri != null) {
                        var rert = uri!!.toString()
                        var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rert))
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        Log.d(TAG,"INTENT TRIGGERED: "+url.toString())
                        startActivity(intent)

                    }
```

but it doesn't open the url as i thought, instead it just opens my app. So how can Make this url ( such as, https://mynewdom.com/anysuffix ) to open inside my webview when clicked from any other apps?

I would always appreciate any help/corrections regarding this.